# efetch with too many accession number

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a problem with the following script. I´m trying to submit 110 000 NCBI accession IDS to recover fasta sequences but i don´t get them all since (guess need some sort of batch submission mode or will not get all sequences). i think i have to use batch mode but not sure how to do it ?
Here is the script i´m using.

```
import sys
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO


#define email for entrez login
db           = "nuccore"
Entrez.email = "someone@email.com"

#load accessions from arguments
if len(sys.argv[1:]) > 1:
  accs = sys.argv[1:]
else: #load accesions from stdin  
  accs = [ l.strip() for l in sys.stdin if l.strip() ]
#fetch
sys.stderr.write( "Fetching %s entries from GenBank: %s\n" % (len(accs), ", ".join(accs[:10])))
for i,acc in enumerate(accs):
  try:
    sys.stderr.write( " %9i %s          \r" % (i+1,acc))  
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db=db, rettype="fasta", id=acc)
    seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "fasta")

    if (len(seq_record.seq) > 0):
      header = ">" + seq_record.description + " Len:" , len(seq_record.seq)
      print(",".join(str(x) for x in header))
      print(seq_record.seq)
  except:
    sys.stderr.write( "Error! Cannot fetch: %s        \n" % acc)
```

`./acc2fasta.py 163345 303239` ... ...  (up to 110 000).

Actually i use `cat acc_file | acc2fasta.py`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please be more specific, do you get an error? Presumably you're redirecting to an output file rather than printing to screen?

Comment: you can feed a comma separated list of ids to `Entrez.efetch()`

Comment: I am not getting any error. The script works well, however Entrez.efetch is limited to 100000 ids so when you submit 110000 entries some will fall out. I was wondering what is the best strategy and if biopython has a batchmode utility to solve this ?

Comment: But currently you're only submitting your ids 1 by 1, not all at once

Comment: Yes, i could actually submit a range each time (say blocks of 100 or 1000), so just wondering if this is the best approach ?? 
One by one approach will result in connection being disconnected from NCBI

Comment: for that many sequences isn't there a fasta file you can download from their ftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can feed a comma separated list of ids to `Entrez.efetch()`. So in your case instead of looping with `enumerate()`, try:

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db=db, rettype="fasta", id=','.join(accs))
#                                                  ^ comma separated list of ids
```

If you want smaller batches then proceed a similar way but still looping and submitting say 1000 elements at a time.

Comment: Ok let´s give a try.